# Cannot destructure property as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize for an mssql database.
Here is the model for Orders:

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import { db } from "../config/database.js";

const Orders = db.define(
  "order",
  {
    customerName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    customerAddress: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    phoneNumber: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

export { Orders };
```

I have the http post written as the following:

```
router.post("/orders", async (req, res) => {
  const { customerName, customerAddress, phoneNumber, email } = req.body;
  const order = await Orders.create({
    customerName,
    customerAddress,
    phoneNumber,
    email,
  });
  res.json(order);
});
```

But when I'm trying to post from Postman or from my frontend i get the following message:

```
 const { customerName, customerAddress, phoneNumber, email } = req.body;
          ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'customerName' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.
```

This is my frontend:

```
function submit(e) {
    console.log(order);
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3002/parts/orders", {
        customerName: order.customerName,
        customerAddress: order.customerAddress,
        phoneNumber: order.phoneNumber,
        email: order.email,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  }
```

This function is used by the form that is submitted. It sends the data to /parts/orders because i've changed routing. I have the console.log(order) so I can see that it really is an order with data. This is what I get in console so I suppose the order has data in it and so should the req.body.
`{customerName: "testman", customerAddress: "test street", phoneNumber: "testnumber", email: "test@gmail.com"}`

So why isn't my database getting the data it's supposed to?

Comment: Have you defined the bodyparser.json middleware?

Comment: Have you tried `const { ... } = req.body ?? {}`, because it looks like the `body` of the `req` is `null` per the error message.

Comment: Yea alright thank you  very much @Ayzrian i accidently deleted the app.use(express.json()) line somehow

Answer (score 0):

I didnt have
`app.user(express.json())`
in my index.js file